# Type a variable such that it conforms to the signature of a (non-static) member function

Tags: typescript, types, interface

I have an interface like this:

```
export declare class DRMAgent extends HTMLObjectElement {
    onDRMMessageResult(msgID: string, resultMsg: string, resultCode: number);
}
```

And I'd like to instantiate a resultHandler following the signature of `onDRMMessageResult`, but I'm not sure how to write the type (I've tried `DRMAgent.onDRMMessageResult` below, but this complains: `"TS2339: Property 'onDRMMessageResult' does not exist on type typeof DRMAgent"`, presumably because it's not a static property).

```
let drmagent: DRMAgent = document.getElementById('drmagent') as DRMAgent;
let resultHandler: DRMAgent.onDRMMessageResult =
    (msgID: string, resultMsg: string, resultCode: number) => {
        // handle result
    } 
drmagent.onDRMMessageResult = resultHandler;
```

What's the correct way to write the type for `resultHandler`?

Note: I know that I can type it as `(msgID: string, resultMsg: string, resultCode: number)=>any`, but that requires copy-pasting the parameters directly from the interface. I'd like to know whether it is possible to type it just by referring to the name of the interface's member function somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare it with a literal:

```
export declare class DRMAgent extends HTMLObjectElement {
    onDRMMessageResult(msgID: string, resultMsg: string, resultCode: number);
}

let drmagent: DRMAgent = document.getElementById('drmagent') as DRMAgent;
let resultHandler: (msgID: string, resultMsg: string, resultCode: number) => void =
    (msgID: string, resultMsg: string, resultCode: number) => {
        // handle result
    } 
drmagent.onDRMMessageResult = resultHandler;
```

Or just once with a type alias:

```
type OnDrmMessageResult = (msgID: string, resultMsg: string, resultCode: number) => void;

export declare class DRMAgent extends HTMLObjectElement {
    onDRMMessageResult: OnDrmMessageResult;
}

let drmagent: DRMAgent = document.getElementById('drmagent') as DRMAgent;
let resultHandler: OnDrmMessageResult =
    (msgID: string, resultMsg: string, resultCode: number) => {
        // handle result
    } 
drmagent.onDRMMessageResult = resultHandler;
```